# Cucumber test stops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber

I'm using Rails 2 in my Rails project. While running all Cucumber features, the test stops without any error message. After that I have to quit the testing in order to start again.

I have no idea why it stops.

Any ideas?

I'm working on Mac OS X Snow Leopard if that helps?

[EDIT]
Learned that this was a problem with the JAVA_OPTS settings. Setting them up to a higher number made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that it could be many things, but what about an infinite redirection loop ? I would take a look at my redirects. What happens if you do the scenario by hand ? Does it work ?

Comment: I just found out, that rake db:test:purge --trace stops after the following steps 
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:test:purge